# Are my .NET ToolStripItem event handlers causing a memory leak?

Tags: .net, vb.net, event-handling, garbage-collection

I have a vb.NET application. In some forms, I use a DataGridView pulling records from a SQL Server database. Depending on the content of a specific row, I enable a right-click menu on the rows that is context-dependent. Basically I generate the ContextMenuStrip on-demand when the user right clicks on a row. Each ContextMenuStrip contains one or more ToolStripItem objects. Each of those will have an onClick event handler that points to a Sub within the form. I have multiple concerns with these handlers.

1. When the form is closed, are these handlers all taken care of by GC, since they are only listening to a Click event for an object inside the form?
2. When a user right-clicks on a row, event handlers are created - do they get disposed of when the ContextMenuStrip closes? Or do they stick around?
3. Should I be explicitly disposing these handlers? And if so, when and how?

Here is an example of my code that handles the MouseDown event on a DataGridView row:

```
    Private Sub DataGridLoc_MouseDown(sender As DataGridView, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridLocations.MouseDown
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
            Dim currentMouseOverRow = DataGridLocations.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
            Dim row = sender.Rows(currentMouseOverRow).DataBoundItem.Row
            If (currentMouseOverRow >= 0) Then
                sender.ClearSelection()
                sender.Rows(currentMouseOverRow).Selected = True
                Dim locType = If((row("StateVal") And LocState.Parent) = 0, "container", "location")
                Dim m As New ContextMenuStrip()
                If locType = "container" Then m.Items.Add($"Remove{If(IfDBNull(row("Pieces"), 0) > 0, " and Merge", "")} the {locType} {row("LocationName")}", Nothing, AddressOf OnClick_LocRemove).Tag = currentMouseOverRow
                m.Items.Add($"Rename {locType} {row("LocationName")}", Nothing, AddressOf OnClick_LocEdit).Tag = currentMouseOverRow
                m.Items.Add($"Edit the discount percent of {row("LocationName")}", Nothing, AddressOf OnClick_LocDisc).Tag = currentMouseOverRow
                If locType = "container" Then
                    m.Items.Add($"Make this container {IIf(row("Defaultable"), "NOT ", "")}Defaultable", Nothing, AddressOf OnClick_LocDefaultable).Tag = currentMouseOverRow
                    m.Items.Add("Change parent Location", Nothing, AddressOf OnClick_ChangeParent).Tag = currentMouseOverRow
                    m.Items.Add($"Edit container type: '{row("LocType")}'", Nothing, AddressOf OnClick_ChangeLocType).Tag = currentMouseOverRow
                End If
                m.Show(DataGridLocations, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You just need one class CMS for this rather than keep creating new ones. You have the same number of items, same handlers, then create one with the initial values, hook the event handlers up, and in the `MouseDown` just set the `.Text` property of each `TSMI` according to the given condition/row....

Comment: @dr.null That's an interesting idea, but a more complicated implementation, so if my way is causing a memory leak I'll absolutely try it. But if it's not causing a problem, it doesn't seem worth doing. I still don't know if my way is causing a memory problem or not

Comment: Writing good, optimized, logical code is worth doing. Your code won't cause a crash or the blue-screen. In other scenarios like dealing with graphics, IO tasks...etc shall lead to disasters. Flooding the memory with _zombies_ (disposable objects) and relying on the GC to do the housekeeping for you is not a good practice. At some possible critical points, It could be too late for the GC to take actions. If you know how to make your code better then make it better.

Comment: To the actual question.  Is this causing memory leaks.  Yeah, probably to some degree but would it be enough to worry about would be the next question.  All in all though I would 100% agree with what @dr.null has suggested.  Create it once and simplify the entire process means far less room anything to possibly go wrong.  Would have a guess suggesting what you're doing here may well cause you further up stream issues around scope of this context menu

Comment: As in any performance question, I would recommend profiling.  The Visual Studio profiler includes the ability to compare the managed heap between different checkpoints, which can be helpful to see if there are large objects within your control that need to be reclaimed.

Comment: In general, memory leaks are a complicated topic in managed land, because even memory which is released to be reclaimed may still remain "allocated" for a long time.  The GC is optimized to recover short-lived objects, so medium- to long-lived objects may require an explicit zero-generation GC cycle to recover the memory (which will be costly performance-wise).